# Touchpad two finger drag as middle click drag

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

I'm using an apple magic trackpad 2 on a fresh install, everything works great gestures and all.

However in Blender behavior is quite different, two fingers zooms in and out when it should orbit the camera.

I believe what I need is for two finger drag to act as middle mouse drag.

Is it possible to customize input in this way? If so I would also customize three finger drag to “shift + middle mouse drag”

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: My bad, new to linux. Using Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 straight off their site.